# How do I get git svn diff to use svn's internal diff engine?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I need to make git svn diff produce diffs that are basically line-for-line equivalent to a diff produced by svn diff.

I'm quite familiar with various scripts, like [git-svn-diff.sh](https://gist.github.com/833214), that will make the patch compatible with svn, but where the diff is ambiguous, the two diff engines often differ, and I need to normalize this.  Basically, I need git svn diff, svn diff, and svnlook diff (for a svn pre-commit hook) to all produce exact-same patches (modulo translation), and as far as I can tell, since I can't override svnlook's diff engine, I am stuck using the internal diff engine for svn.

That's fine, except there doesn't seem to be a tool that comes with svn that will let you diff two files with the internal engine.  I see that the source code has a tools/diff/diff.c, but no binary is distributed.  Am I stuck distributing this tool myself, does it exist and I missed it, or can I make a pre-commit hook produce a patch for a transaction using a different diff engine?

Comment: The various `git-svn-diff` scripts out there all seem to have issues. I could find no other way however. This is the best I could come up with so far (but I found today that it occasionally strips the whitespace between `---`/`+++` and the file name, though I didn't have time today to finish debugging that, otherwise it appears identical to my other `svn diff` tests): https://gist.github.com/rage-shadowman/6325382 (disclaimer: my gist, though forked from somebody else's). Feel free to fork and fix.

Comment: Actually my script was forked from the one you linked to, which was the closest I could find to the actual `svn diff` output before I cleaned it up and fixed all the problems I could find (then I saw 1 more issue this morning which still needs to be fixed).

Comment: Found the bug in my `git-svn-diff` script. It was an issue with new files and has been fixed. It now works perfectly as far as I can tell and I've been using it to generate patches from my `git-svn` project for our Crucible code review server that is backed by our SVN server. I can see no differences in its output and the output of `svn diff`. If you find any, please add a comment to my gist page and I'll try to sort it out.

Comment: @ShadowCreeper I needed this for Crucible, and your script worked great. Thank you. Please convert your comment to an answer to make it more visible.